# How can I DRY up these functions with static variables (C++)?

Tags: c++, static-variables

I'm doing a problem from Project Euler that involves finding Triangle, Square, Pentagonal, ..., Octagonal numbers, so I'm trying to create this utility that will validate each kind of number. I decided to create sieves for each set of numbers for fast accessing, and I'm storing it in a static array. I was able to make a generic function that will generate each sieve, but that leaves each of the validation functions extremely similar. I don't see a good way to keep from repeating the code in these functions because of the way they use the static bool arrays. What are some ideas you have for DRYing this up?

```
#ifndef FIGURATE_NUMBERS
#define FIGURATE_NUMBERS

#define SIEVE_MAX 10000

void populateFigurateSieve(bool* sieve, const int ADDER_INCREASE)
{
    int number = 0;
    int adder = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIEVE_MAX; i++)
    {
        if (i == number)
        {
            sieve[i] = true;
            number += adder;
            adder += ADDER_INCREASE;
        }
        else
        {
            sieve[i] = false;
        }
    }

    return;
}

bool isTriangleNumber(long long int n)
{
    static bool triangleNumberSieve[SIEVE_MAX];
    static bool initialized = false;

    if (!initialized)
    {
        populateFigurateSieve(triangleNumberSieve, 1);
        initialized = true;
    }

    return triangleNumberSieve[n];
}

bool isSquareNumber(long long int n)
{
    static bool squareNumberSieve[SIEVE_MAX];
    static bool initialized = false;

    if (!initialized)
    {
        populateFigurateSieve(squareNumberSieve, 2);
        initialized = true;
    }

    return squareNumberSieve[n];
}

bool isPentagonalNumber(long long int n)
{
    static bool pentagonalNumberSieve[SIEVE_MAX];
    static bool initialized = false;

    if (!initialized)
    {
        populateFigurateSieve(pentagonalNumberSieve, 3);
        initialized = true;
    }

    return pentagonalNumberSieve[n];
}

#endif
```

Comment: This is probably a better fit for [CodeReview], since you have working code but are trying to make it better.

Answer (score 2):

I admire your C approach, but here in C++ people like classes. (-: For example, they allow you to Not Repeat Yourself by abstracting over constant values. You have the same code for three different step constants: 1, 2 and 3, so you can create a template for them using something like this:

```cpp
#include <vector>

constexpr long long SIEVE_MAX = 10000;

template <int ADDER_INCREASE>
class GenericSieve
{
    static std::vector<bool> Sieve;

    static std::vector<bool> populated_sieve()
    {
        int number = 0;
        int adder = 1;
        std::vector<bool> sieve(SIEVE_MAX);

        for (int i = 0; i < SIEVE_MAX; i++)
        {
            if (i == number)
            {
                sieve[i] = true;
                number += adder;
                adder += ADDER_INCREASE;
            }
            else
            {
                sieve[i] = false;
            }
        }

        return sieve;
    }
public:
    static bool belongs(long long n)
    {
        if (Sieve.size() == 0)
        {
            Sieve = populated_sieve();
        }
        return Sieve.at(n);
    }
};
template<int inc>
std::vector<bool> GenericSieve<inc>::Sieve;

// define a sieve for every number you like
using TriangularSieve = GenericSieve<1>;
using SquareSieve = GenericSieve<2>;
using PentagonalSieve = GenericSieve<3>;

// define functions if you will
bool isTriangleNumber(long long int n)
{
    return TriangularSieve::belongs(n);
}
bool isSquareNumber(long long int n)
{
    return SquareSieve::belongs(n);
}
bool isPentagonalNumber(long long int n)
{
    return PentagonalSieve::belongs(n);
}
```

As you can see, I mostly used your code, but now it's all static functions of templated classes.

Comment: That's a lot of overhead compared to the C-style code as you call it. Besides, if a class consists entirely of static methods.... Why make it a class? Freestanding functions are perfectly fine in C++. That said, I think you might have brought up a good point about possibly using templates here. That's not something I thought of.

Comment: I absolutely forgot about templates. Great answer

Comment: @Isaiah I don't think there will be much runtime overhead, but that needs checking either way, good notice. As for the class, yeah i agree using only functions is much cleaner, but this way it's much easier to create static variables for each template parameter. If you have a cleaner solution without classes, I would really like to learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

Template is indeed a way to factorize code, for example:

```
template <std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<bool, N> make_sieve(std::size_t ADDER_INCREASE)
{
    std::size_t number = 0;
    std::size_t adder = 1;
    std::array<bool, N> sieve{};

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (i == number)
        {
            sieve[i] = true;
            number += adder;
            adder += ADDER_INCREASE;
        }
        else
        {
            sieve[i] = false;
        }
    }
    return sieve;
}

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t Sieve>
constexpr bool belongs(long long n)
{
    constexpr auto sieve = make_sieve<N>(Sieve);

    return sieve[n];
}

constexpr std::size_t SIEVE_MAX = 10'000;

constexpr bool isTriangleNumber(long long int n) { return belongs<SIEVE_MAX, 1>(n); }
constexpr bool isSquareNumber(long long int n) { return belongs<SIEVE_MAX, 2>(n); }
constexpr bool isPentagonalNumber(long long int n) { return belongs<SIEVE_MAX, 3>(n); }
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cee4593ce18bd76c)

(I would have preferred `std::bitset`, but missing some constexpr methods :( )
(If you cannot use `constexpr`, `static const auto sieve = make_sieve<N>(Sieve);` would allow to compute it only once, without your init flag).

Answer (score 0):

```
void doInit(bool& initialized, bool* sieve, int adderIncrease) {
  if (!initialized) {
    populateFigurateSieve(sieve, adderIncrease);
    initialized = true;
  }
}
```

You then call it with the same parameters as you were calling `populateFigurateSieve` before except you also pass the `initialized` variable at the front.

That saves 2 lines in each function by moving the initialization check to a function rather than repeating 90% of it each time.

---

The best way to follow the DRY principle is by trying to see what similar code have in common. Here, I noticed you were performing the same initialization check for each function with the primary difference being how you called the `populateFigurateSieve` function. I then made the function by parameterizing the differences while keeping the same general structure from the similarities.

Edit: Better yet, you don't need the initialized variable. Instead of passing a pointer to the populate function, you can have it create and return an array:

```
#include <array>
// ...
std::array<bool, SIEVE_MAX> populateFigurateSieve(const int ADDER_INCREASE) {
  std::array<bool, SIEVE_MAX> sieve {};
  // ... (Your code should still work...,)
  return sieve;
}
// ...
// When making the sieve in the function:
static std::array<bool, SIEVE_MAX> sieve = populateFigurateSieve( /* Required value here */);
// No longer need initialized variable
// ....
```